# Jira: Sort with duedate and priority

Tags: jira, jql

For managing my own tasks I want to order them by priority DESC but also not miss the time critical ones which have a due date in upcoming or already passed. Does anybody know a way to sort like this in Jira Query Language (JQL)? E.g. in SQL:

```
ORDER BY IF(duedate<NOW(), duedate, 0) ASC, priority DESC
```

Any idea or workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JIRA doesn't let you create new values to order by within JQL. The heavyweight way to do it would be to have a calculated custom field based on DueDate and now(), then sort by that field. The lighter weight way for a few issues might be to use GreenHopper and card colors or swimlanes by query. The way I'd do for lots of issues is to have two queries and look at the top results in each one.

Comment: Thank you! And there is also no way to have functions in order by, correct?